# How to display start and end times in one cell in excel?

Tags: excel, time, schedule

I have a schedule for work that lists employees shifts as durations, i.e. 11-7, 1030-6, etc. within a single cell. If these were single times like 6, 1130, etc, I could convert to time format easily, but how can I make these cells display the shift start and end time in time format?
The goal is to have excel use these times to sort and filter the corresponding employees on another sheet according to their scheduled shift. Is there a way to display "hh:mm-hh:mm" to represent a shift in one cell?

Comment: How is the time information entered into the cell in the first place? This can be done with a formula if a helper column is allowed, or with VBA if the times must remain in the same cell.

Comment: It's being entered as plain numbers, 11-7, 1030-5, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using formulas, but you have to be specific about formats and testing the entries.

The primary piece of the formula to understand is how to separate the time "values" on either side of the "-". ***This solution assumes that a dash ("-") will ALWAYS be present in the cell.*** For the shift entry "2-11" (assume this is in cell A2), you can use a combination of `FIND`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT` to separate all the characters on either side of the "-" using these formulas

```
Cell A2 contains "2-11"
LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1           returns  "2"
RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2))   returns "11"
```

IMPORTANT:  these formulas now become "the time value" and will be repeated inside a larger formula.

From here on out, it's a matter of reformatting the string into a time-formatted string by adding a colon ":" at the appropriate place in the string in order to create an Excel time value.

Helper columns are used to get all the values cleanly, as shown in this example:

[image]

Formula in B2: `=IF(LEN(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))<=2,TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)&":00"),TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-3)&":"&RIGHT(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1),2)))`

Formula in C2:
`=TIMEVALUE(IF(LEN(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)))<=2,RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2))&":00",LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)),LEN(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)))-2)&":"&RIGHT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)),2)))`

Formula in D2: `=IF(C2>B2,C2,C2+TIME(12,0,0))`

Formula in E2: `=(D2-B2)*24`

Formula in F2: `=TEXT(B2,"hh:mm")&" - "&TEXT(D2,"hh:mm")`